# X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication -- on CentOS, for all users (including root)

Tags: centos, x11, sshd

I'm configuring a small computing cluster with CentOS. The last step is setting up X11 forwarding, and here I find problems that I cannot solve.

On all compute nodes except one, I can set up everything by just installing xorg-x11-server-Xorg and xorg-x11-xauth with `yum`, then starting Xorg (as root). Signing in as any user with `ssh -X`, X forwarding works without a problem.

However, on the last server, I get the following message when signing in with `ssh -X` (as root or as any other user) and trying to start an X application (Molden in this case):

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Molden: cannot connect to X server host:11.0
```

I have tried several fixes I have found online, including

- Disabling SElinux
- Checking that the ownership of `.Xauthority` files are correct
- Deleting `.Xauthority`
- Checking that X11 forwarding is enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (and no local `ssh_config` files exist that can overwrite this)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling xorg-x11-server-Xorg and xorg-x11-xauth to make sure both packages are installed directly by the root user, not through `sudo yum install` (I do not understand why this would affect anything, but it has been suggested)

Using verbose mode and checking all system log files gives no further hints to how to solve the problem. The only guess I have is that the hostname configuration is somewhat different on the trouble-causing node. Changing the host name configuration on this server to be the same as on the other servers did not give any results.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: check firewall settings? `systemd`?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -vvv -X ...`? Putting it on pastebin would suffice.

Comment: Does `ssh -Y` make a difference? Please post the output of `ssh -vvv -X xterm` and of `ssh -X strace xterm`.